# В кондитерской продают 7 видов пирожных. Сколькими способами можно купить 15 пирожных?

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, дискретная-математика

Снова всем привет!

Задача:
В кондитерской продают 7 видов пирожных. Сколькими способами можно купить 15 пирожных? Сколькими способами можно это сделать так, чтобы среди них оказались пирожные каждого вида?

Полагаю, что на первый вопрос можно ответить, используя формулу сочетаний с повторениями:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО:
Если пользоваться побитовым способом и считать через разделители то получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как же так? Или я в чём-то ошибся?

На второй вопрос ответить не смог.

Буду очень благодарен за объяснения!)

Comment: Первый вопрос: *"Сколькими способами можно купить 15 пирожных?"* - только **одним** способом - купить 15 пирожных!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае вопрос о выборке с повторениями (см., например, https://ya-znau.ru/znaniya/zn/80), так что количество способов выбора 15 пирожных из 7 видов равно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрать пирожные так, чтоб были все 7 видов, можно 3003 способами: поскольку порядок не играет роли, первые 7 пирожных выберем разными, а остальные 8 - как угодно, т.е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

способами.

Вы просто неверно записали формулу для сочетаний с повторениями...

Comment: Спасибо большое за пояснения! Буду внимательнее...